# What exactly is modified by setting the GNOME display scale through GUI?

Tags: gnome, gnome-3, hidpi

After setting the display scale to 200% through "GNOME Settings" (`gnome-control-center display`), I check `scaling-factor` through the command line:

```sh
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor
uint32 1
```

As you can see, the `scaling-factor` is still 1 (100%). So what exactly is modified by setting the GNOME display scale through GUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying the scaling factor through the UI modifies the file ~/.config/monitors.xml, and sets the value of the tag `<scale></scale>` to the appropriate number amount for all active monitors.

As to what *that* does, [Garet's answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/152611) describes it pretty well.

GNOME uses xrandr to modify display settings on the fly using the content from the ~/.config/monitors.xml file. Once the display setting is changed, I believe GNOME restarts the [display manager](https://askubuntu.com/a/264411/1428819) to apply the new settings.

Comment: Thank you for the information. To be honest, what I really want to do is to imitate the GNOME Settings to set a scale on the fly but in the command line. And the way to achieve this is using the D-Bus interface `org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig`.